Determining orientation of an IMU inside rocket
I currently have an Adafruit ISM330DHCX IMU on the way, and it will be put inside of a rocket which will be controlled using Thrust Vector Control (controlling the engine's thrust on 2 axes).
I now am facing the issue of determining the orientation of the rocket in flight. I have been reading around, and I have heard lots about fusing the gyro and accelerometer readings, but I have also heard from people who have flown similar rockets that accelerometer data cannot be trusted in flight because of the thrust (is this even true?).
I have discovered the Madgwick AHRS algorithm developed for Arduino, and I am thinking of using that. Will it still provide correct orientation for roll, pitch, and yaw if I just provide it with raw gyro values from the IMU, and provide the integer 0 for accelerometer values during flight?
Is this a good way of computing orientation of the sensor? If not, is there a better way that is accurate for a rocket?

IMU's are generally not used for long term position fixes, or tracking.  That is what an INU, or INS (Inertial navigation system) does.  For example, we mount IMU's rigidly to an antenna in the nose of an aircraft.  The IMU measures the short term variations in antenna position relative to the airframe (from things like vibration or flexing of the structure) so that the antenna beam pointing can be accurately established.

It really isn't clear what you're asking here. There's one question in the title, but a couple of different questions in the body. And since you haven't specified what level of performance you want to achieve, there's no way to determine whether the device and/or the algorithm(s) you've chosen will meet it. I think you're going to need to make a few flights just to gather some raw sensor data, and then spend a couple of weeks running that data through various algorithms to see whether you get the results you want.

Life is hard.

In principle, you cannot determine orientation from gyro input alone.  Gyros give you a rate, so at best you can only calculate a delta from some previous orientation.

In principle, you can determine orientation from a known starting orientation and gyro data.
In practice, the period of time over which this orientation inference is useful is limited by how bad your gyros are, how accurate your starting orientation was, and how long the thing has been going on dead reckoning.


In principle and in at least some practice, you can combine accelerometer and gyro data for a better reading.  However:

You need accelerometers that are accurate enough and won't saturate (or you need to know your orientation when they accelerometers stop saturating).
If people who reported problems are at the "paste things together using Arduinos" stage, then chances are that there's just not product out there that's good enough and available to hobbyists.
You will only increase the accuracy of your dead reckoning.


In principle and in practice, you can combine acceleration, gyro, and position (i.e. GPS) together to get accurate orientation.  I've done this for cars.  However this is freaking hard.
An IMU plus a compass (sometimes sold as a "nine-axis IMU") would probably work. You may want to consider that, especially if you just care about orientation.  The compass will take care of the non-moving component of the orientation (which the gyro can't do at all), while the gyro will deal with the fast-moving components of the orientation (which the compass can't do well at all).


I'd assume this rocket is unlikely to leave earth's magnetic field (deep space missions aren't usually done using arduinos and adafruit modules), but for space applications it should be noted that compasses rely on that magnetic field to work! At sufficiently high altitudes you may need to compensate for the difference.
